# Start a tmux detached on boot up under a user

Tags: ubuntu, boot, tmux, rc.local

I'm on ubuntu 19 and I created the file /etc/rc.local and added this to the file:

```
/bin/su -l mysuser -c "/usr/bin/tmux new-session -s foobar -d"
```

I tried running this line by pasting it to the command line and it works.

But it doesn't seem to work on boot when i su to myuser and do a "tmux a" to reattach. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Reason why is that you need to make sure /etc/rc.local is executable and the file needs to be in this format:

```
#!/bin/sh -e 
/bin/su -l myuser -c "/usr/bin/tmux new-session -s session_name -d"
exit 0
```

Then you can test to make sure the service is working with:

**systemctl status rc-local.service**

and enable with:

**systemctl enable rc-local**